# Hibernate cascading update (inverse/mappedBy)

Tags: java, hibernate, dao

I have 2 objects defined:

```
class Customer
{
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="customer", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="ORDER_ID", nullable=false)
    private Set<Order> orders;
}


class Order
{
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="CUSTOMER_ID", nullable=false, insertable=true, updatable=false)
    private Customer customer;
}
```

One customer can have many orders.

In my logic, I will modify the property of Customer and create a new order for the customer. Then I want to persist the new created order into database without updating the customer.

But currently when I save(order), it will also update the customer. How to insert the order without updating the customer?

Means, this is a one to many mapping. I modified the one object and created one "many" object. I want to save the "many" object without updating the "one" object.

Comment: Show us your code. I don't see why saving a new order would modify the customer.

Comment: This will perpahs help you a little more http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/different-between-cascade-and-inverse/

Answer (score 0):

In this case I prefer to store "many" object with "one"s object ID specified ofcourse if you already know it. Try to save new Order with CUSTOMER_ID specified. It appiers in Customer object next time it was loaded.